# Neo4j Cypher - How to limit 50% of MATCH results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, limit

I want to limit by 50% of results from `MATCH` but it looks like `LIMIT` doesn't accept dynamic value.

I tried:

```
MATCH (:Profile) 
WITH COUNT(*) AS c
MATCH (n:Profile)
WITH n ORDER BY rand() LIMIT toInt(c * 0.5) 
RETURN n
```

Then I got the error:

```
It is not allowed to refer to variables in LIMIT
```

So is there any way to do that without using 2 separate queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I see it.

1. Get all profiles and create a randomized number with each row
2. Collect all profiles into a list of profiles and sorted by randomized number (r)
3. Calculate the 50% of the size of the profile list
4. Unwind the list from start to cnt then return each node

```
MATCH (n:Profile) 
WITH n, rand() as r ORDER by r 
WITH collect(n) as profile_lst
WITH profile_lst, toInt(size(profile_lst)/2) as cnt
UNWIND profile_lst[0..cnt] as prof
RETURN prof
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [apoc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/) plugin installed, you can use the [apoc.coll.randomItems](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.randomItems/) function to get a random 50%:

```
MATCH (n:Profile)
WITH COLLECT(n) AS people
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(people, SIZE(people)/2) as profile_lst
UNWIND profile_lst as prof
RETURN prof
```